# Can GNU FindUtils be configured to skip a directory?

Tags: debian, locate, updatedb

When I run `updatedb` I get an error "Permission denied" to `/run/user`

```
$ sudo updatedb
/usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
```

Note my version of `updatedb` comes from the package [`locate`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/findutils/) which is itself just [GNU Findutils](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/findutils/). My `updatedb` eventually resolves via symlinks to `updatedb.findutils`. Here you can see [`man 1 updatedb.findutils`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/locate/updatedb.findutils.1.en.html) which doesn't mention a configuration file at all. Is there anyway to configure GNU Findutils to skip searching in a directory?

Note if I do this,

```
sudo updatedb --prunepaths=/run
```

It works fine. If I do this,

```
echo 'PRUNEPATHS = "/run/user/"' | sudo tee /etc/updatedb.conf
```

I still get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GNU FindUtil's locate does not support a configuration file.

GNU FindUtil's locate does not support this. The confusion between mlocate, [plocate](https://plocate.sesse.net/), and GNU FindUtils's locate (the default) [seems to come up a lot.](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/12/msg00720.html)

The newest one is [`plocate`](https://plocate.sesse.net/). It ships with a `/etc/updatedb.conf` that contains,

```
PRUNEFS="NFS afs autofs binfmt_misc ceph cgroup cgroup2 cifs coda configfs curlftpfs debugfs devfs devpts devtmpfs ecryptfs ftpfs fuse.ceph fuse.glusterfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse fuse.mfs fuse.rozofs fuse.sshfs fusectl fusesmb hugetlbfs iso9660 lustre lustre_lite mfs mqueue ncpfs nfs nfs4 ocfs ocfs2 proc pstore rpc_pipefs securityfs shfs smbfs sysfs tmpfs tracefs udev udf usbfs"
```

Because that includes `tmpfs` it will not index `/var/run`